# Do I need to declare personal electronics at UK customs

Tags: united-kingdom

I am moving to the UK from India on work visa and thinking of moving with following electronics:

1. Two MacBooks (both are work laptops)
2. Two mobile phones (both are work phones)
3. One personal mobile
4. An Xbox
5. A couple of headphones

The combined value of these items is well above the allowed personal limit. Do I still need to declare these to customs, if I am only using these for personal use? And will be taking them back with me if I leave the country

Comment: Are the company goods their propriety or are they yours?

Answer (score 1):

The HMRC has a website ([link](https://www.gov.uk/bringing-goods-into-uk-personal-use/declaring-goods)) that'll tell you if, and how much is owed, you need to declare your personal goods.

Are the work electronics yours or your your company's? I'd believe, if they're company devices, *don't quote me on this* that it will not count but contact HMRC before doing anything

For the other items, sure, it will need to be appropriately declared (if applicable)

**EDIT:** As per @Traveler comment, a better link to your situation is the one to use when you move to the UK and not just visit, [link](https://www.gov.uk/moving-to-uk)

According to the site, you might be able to invoke a Transfer of Residence claim to be relieved from tax/duties. If you don't qualify, the original answer still stands

Comment: This link https://www.gov.uk/moving-to-uk is more appropriate, given the OP has a work visa and is presumably transferring their place of residence to the UK. The question really belongs on Expatriates

Comment: Yes, that is better, will edit @Traveller

Comment: Thank you so much. This is helpful :)